# Loop through function until unique value

Tags: powershell

I made a powershell script to do some stuff with csv files. I have a problem with my second import.
The script is divided in few section, like this :

Firt part ---- Classic variables declaration 
Second part ---- Loop through my first csv 
Third part ---- Function to loop through ma second csv 
Last part ---- Actions with 3 last sections

My function in the **third part** look like this :

```
Function FindRef {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $Name
)
$RefList = Import-Csv "PATHTOMYCSV\ref.csv" -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($Ref in $RefList) {
     if ($Ref.Company -eq $Name -or $Ref.Model -eq $Name) {          
        Write-Host "$($Ref.Company), $($Ref.Model) and reference is $($Ref.Reference)"
        $PhoneRef =  $Ref.reference 
    }
}
```

}

When I call y function "***FindRef***" with "Samsung" parameter for example it return me :

```
Samsung Galaxy A21s REF
Samsung Galaxy J2 Core REF
Samsung Galaxy A Quantum REF
Samsung Galaxy A71 REF
Samsung Galaxy A51 REF 
Samsung Galaxy A21 REF 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite REF
Samsung Galaxy M11 REF 
Samsung Galaxy A31 REF
Samsung Galaxy A41 REF 
Samsung Galaxy M21 REF 
Samsung Galaxy A11 REF 
Samsung Galaxy M31 REF 
Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra 5G REF 
Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra REF
Samsung Galaxy S20+ REF
Samsung Galaxy Z Flip REF 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 REF
```

In the example above with the name "**Samsung**", I have too many results, I need only one reference.

I would like to loop on this function as long as it returns several results, until I have a unique reference.

I don't see how to do this, do you have any ideas?

PS : The result of my function when I call it :

[image: RefFunction powershell]

My csv :

[Ref.csv](https://pastebin.com/Ye5fzgBj)
Regards,

Comment: The shown result does not come from `FindRef` function, Please share a [mcve] incl. a non-trivial part of `ref.csv` file. There is an unclear operation in your code snippet `foreach ($Ref in $RefList) {$Ref =  $Ref.reference}` (changing a _loop control variable_ `$Ref` in an illegal manner?).

Comment: Exact ! I made a mistake when copying part of my code. 
I correct in my post

Comment: "until I have a unique reference" doesn't make sense - you necessarily need to inspect _all_ the references to determine which ones are unique

Comment: So your if condition is too broad. By doing `($Ref.Company -eq $Name -or $Ref.Model -eq $Name)`, and simply search for `Samsung`, you wil get all items where Company = "Samsung." You need to at least specify a model together with the name to limit the results.

Comment: Yep, I agree with both of you. Mathias, when I said I want a unique reference, it's mean if the user doesn't know exactly the ref, I want him to search a first time with his keyword, just after that I want to replay the function with a precise keyword, and store my result to '$PhoneRef'.  Basically, as long as I have multiple results, I want to replay my function

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to my problem, I share with you. I was obsessed with my function, it was clearly not necessary !

```
$PhoneRef = ""
$RefList = Import-Csv "C:\Users\SRV-VDG\Desktop\Scripy\Ref.csv" -Delimiter ';'
$I=0
while ($I -ne 1) {
    $Name = Read-host -Prompt 'Input the name '
    $I=0
    foreach ($Ref in $RefList) {
        if ($Ref.Company -eq $Name -or $Ref.Model -eq $Name) {          
            Write-Host "$($Ref.Company), $($Ref.Model) and reference is $($Ref.Reference)"
            $PhoneRef =  $Ref.Reference 
            $I++
        }
    }
}
```